# Problem in getting the full rank of a matrix

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra

I have 17 equations I am trying to put them in the matrix form. I am trying to understand why the matrix is not full rank.

```
    ClearAll["Global`*"];
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];

Y = 2*^11;
\[Rho] = 7850;
aa = 0.1*0.1;
Iyy = 0.1^4/12;
L1 = 4;
z[1] = L1/4;
z[3] = (2*L1)/4;
z[2] = (3*L1)/4;

\[Gamma] = 0.5*L1;

beta1 = {1.8751, 4.69409, 7.85476, 10.9955, 14.1372, 17.2788};
beta2 = {3.9266, 7.06858, 10.2102, 13.3518, 16.4934, 19.635, 22.7765, 
   25.9181, 29.0597};

soft = Table[((Cos[\[Beta]*x] - 
        Cosh[\[Beta]*
          x]) - (((Cos[\[Beta]*\[Gamma]] + 
           Cosh[\[Beta]*\[Gamma]])/(Sin[\[Beta]*\[Gamma]] + 
           Sinh[\[Beta]*\[Gamma]]))*(Sin[\[Beta]*x] - 
          Sinh[\[Beta]*x]))) /. \[Beta] -> beta1[[i]]/\[Gamma], {i, 1,
     1}];
beamH = Flatten[{soft}];
Table[Plot[beamH[[i]], {x, 0, \[Gamma]}], {i, 1, Length[beamH]}];
W[1] = Total[
   Table[Subscript[a, 1][i]*beamH[[i]], {i, 1, Length[beamH]}]];
W1xx = Expand[D[W[1], {x, 2}]];
v[1] = 0.5*Y*Iyy*Integrate[Expand[(W1xx)^2], {x, 0, L1}]
t[1] = 0.5*\[Rho]*aa*\[Omega]^2 Integrate[Expand[(W[1])^2], {x, 0, L1}]

varbeam1 = Table[Subscript[a, 1][i], {i, 1, Length[beamH]}]

W[2] = W[1] /. Subscript[a, 1] -> Subscript[a, 2];
W[3] = W[1] /. Subscript[a, 1] -> Subscript[a, 3];
W[4] = W[1] /. Subscript[a, 1] -> Subscript[a, 4];

varbeam2 = varbeam1 /. Subscript[a, 1] -> Subscript[a, 2]
varbeam3 = varbeam1 /. Subscript[a, 1] -> Subscript[a, 3]
varbeam4 = varbeam1 /. Subscript[a, 1] -> Subscript[a, 4]

v[2] = v[1] /. Subscript[a, 1] -> Subscript[a, 2];
v[3] = v[1] /. Subscript[a, 1] -> Subscript[a, 3];
v[4] = v[1] /. Subscript[a, 1] -> Subscript[a, 4];

t[2] = t[1] /. Subscript[a, 1] -> Subscript[a, 2];
t[3] = t[1] /. Subscript[a, 1] -> Subscript[a, 3];
t[4] = t[1] /. Subscript[a, 1] -> Subscript[a, 4];

soft = Table[Sin[((2*i + 1)*\[Pi]*x)/(2*\[Gamma])], {i, 0, 0}];
barH = Flatten[{soft}]
Table[Plot[barH[[ i]], {x, 0, \[Gamma]}], {i, 1, Length[barH]}];

U[1] = Expand[
  Total[Table[Subscript[b, 1][i]*barH[[i]], {i, 1, Length[barH]}]]]
U1x = Expand[D[U[1], {x, 1}]];

v[5] = 0.5*Y*aa*Integrate[Expand[(U1x)^2], {x, 0, \[Gamma]}]
t[5] = 0.5*\[Rho]*aa*\[Omega]^2*
  Integrate[Expand[(U[1])^2], {x, 0, \[Gamma]}]

varbar1 = Table[Subscript[b, 1][i], {i, 1, Length[beamH]}]
U[2] = U[1] /. Subscript[b, 1] -> Subscript[b, 2];
U[3] = U[1] /. Subscript[b, 1] -> Subscript[b, 3];
U[4] = U[1] /. Subscript[b, 1] -> Subscript[b, 4];


varbar2 = varbar1 /. Subscript[b, 1] -> Subscript[b, 2]
varbar3 = varbar1 /. Subscript[b, 1] -> Subscript[b, 3]
varbar4 = varbar1 /. Subscript[b, 1] -> Subscript[b, 4]

v[6] = v[5] /. Subscript[b, 1] -> Subscript[b, 2];
v[7] = v[5] /. Subscript[b, 1] -> Subscript[b, 3];
v[8] = v[5] /. Subscript[b, 1] -> Subscript[b, 4];

t[6] = t[5] /. Subscript[b, 1] -> Subscript[b, 2];
t[7] = t[5] /. Subscript[b, 1] -> Subscript[b, 3];
t[8] = t[5] /. Subscript[b, 1] -> Subscript[b, 4];

(*construction of lagrangian*)
T = Sum[t[i], {i, 8}];
V = Sum[v[i], {i, 8}];

dispcon1 = 
 Total[Table[
   Subscript[\[Lambda], 1][
     i]*((W[1] /. x -> (z[i])) - (U[i + 1] /. x -> (\[Gamma]))), {i, 
    1, 3}]]
dispcon2 = 
 Total[Table[
   Subscript[\[Lambda], 2][
     i]*((U[1] /. x -> (z[i])) - (W[i + 1] /. x -> (\[Gamma]))), {i, 
    1, 3}]]


slopcon = 
 Total[Table[
   Subscript[\[Lambda], 3][
     i]*((D[W[1], {x, 1}] /. 
        x -> (z[i] - 0.00000001)) - (D[W[i + 1], {x, 1}] /. 
        x -> (\[Gamma] - 0.00000001))), {i, 1, 3}]]

vardisp1 = Table[Subscript[\[Lambda], 1][i], {i, 1, 3}];
vardisp2 = Table[Subscript[\[Lambda], 2][i], {i, 1, 3}];
varslop = Table[Subscript[\[Lambda], 3][i], {i, 1, 3}];

var = Flatten[{varbeam1, varbar1, varbeam2, varbar2, varbeam3, 
   varbar3, varbeam4, varbar4, vardisp1, vardisp2, varslop}]

Lg = (T - V) + dispcon1 + dispcon2 + slopcon;

eq = Table[D[Lg, {var[[i]], 1}], {i, 1, Length[var]}];
Rarz = Normal@CoefficientArrays[eq, var][[2]];
MatrixForm[Rarz];
Dimensions[Rarz]
MatrixRank[Rarz]
```

Comment: `Lg` is only linear in the variables `\[Lambda]`. That's why the rank of the coefficientmartix is smaller than expected!

Comment: The OP is now updated with the actual code where I am getting a matrix rank of 16.  Only one is missing to have a full rank matrix. Your suggestion on \[Lambda] being linear seems a little confusing. Could it be any other reason?

Comment: Row 17 is a linear combination of rows 12..16

Comment: `{0,0.707107,1.99999,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}` is 12 the row,  `{-1.67862,0,0,0,1.3765,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}` is 16 the row and this is `{-1.3765,0,0,0,0,0,1.3765,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}` 17 the row. 17th row don't look like a linear combinations of 12 and 16 rows

Comment: 12..16 means 12 through 16.